# Ethereum Consortium Blockchain - Unable to unlock coinbase account - Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum

I am having error trying to unlock the coinbase account. When you first provision to deploy the Consortium Blockchain, you set the passphrase for the mining nodes and the password for the tx node.

When I am ready to deploy my smart contract to my tx-node(which has the blockchain), I get an error to which tells me to unlock my account.

In order to unlock the account, I SSH into my tx-node.

Once, I provide my credentials I have access to the VM.

Then I type

> geth attach

It opens the Geth Console.

Inside the geth console, I type

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase)

I am prompted for my passphrase, I enter it but it keeps returning the error

> Couldn't decrypt key with this passphrase

I use the passphrase, that I put when I first deployed the blockchain but it doesn't work.

I tried multiple times and even redeploying the blockchain, but I am unable to unlock my coinbase account.

I am using this Azure template: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/ethereum-consortium-blockchain-network/

Answer (score 0):

When deploying the Consortium Blockchain on Azure, you set the passphrase for the mining nodes and the password for the tx node however, given the setup your not really looking for the passphrase as requested in the PowerShell.

1. **Copy** `SSH-TO-FIRST-TX-NODE` to clipboard and paste in PowerShell to get to the transaction node
2. **`enter password`**
3. `geth attach`
4. `personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase)`
5. `enter passphrase` **// is actually the password you entered in at the beginning you want to enter**

Be sure to keep this shell open, the password will lock as a security default after being left open for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the OP, and used the same steps provided in the above answer but was still getting the 'could not decrypt key with given passphrase' error.

I was able to unlock a newly created account by following below steps

**$ geth account new**

It will ask for Passphrase and returns the address of new account. Executing following

**$ geth account list**

will display the new account in list of accounts

The new account can be unlocked using

**personal.unlockAccount('new account address', 'passphrase', 'duration')**